# Update JSF Page when a XYZ variable changes in Session Scoped Bean

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I am using;

- primefaces 3.5
- jsf2.0
- glassfish3.1.2

My jsf page displays information with the help of `<h:outputText value="#{myBean.valueThatMayChange}"/>`. I want to update this information on jsf page whenever valueThatMayChange updates in the backing session scoped bean. What is the best approach to get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use technique called *polling*, but there are other solutions. In case you are using PrimeFaces, keep an eye on [`<p:poll>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) tag:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:outputText is="upd" value="#{myBean.valueThatMayChange}"/>
    <p:poll interval="15" update="upd" />  
</h:form>
```

This component basically makes AJAX calls to the server every `interval` seconds to update your tag.